# Fatal Exception: while Running android program

Tags: android

I'm a total new on android and I'm learning at this time to make Android applications. Learn the tutorial from udemy course. Things were well, but for some reasons my application began to crash every time I launch it.

Here is the part where I get crash the app. When I commented this line the app will run, when I remove the app will get crash.

The code is in the page Simple_question.java line number 41.

```
 tvtotallength_yy.setText(simple_question.length);
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJarQ.png)

**FrontPAge.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frontLayout">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/sq"
        android:id="@+id/bsq"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:text="@string/tq"
        android:id="@+id/btq"
        android:layout_below="@id/bsq"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bsq"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/bsq"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/seeother"
        android:id="@+id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_below="@id/btq"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:text="@string/rateapp"
        android:id="@+id/brateapp"
        android:layout_below="@id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state" />

</RelativeLayout>


questions.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/questions_ll"
    android:weightSum="100">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#C2EBFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="XX/"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvxx" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="YY"     
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/tvyy" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#EBFFC2"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Question"
            android:id="@+id/tvquestion"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="15dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Press A button for Answer"
                    android:id="@+id/tvanswer" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#C2EBFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_but"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/bleft"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/answer_state"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/bshowanswer"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/but_right"
            android:id="@+id/bright"
            android:layout_weight="0.15" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**vlaue/Simple_question.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="simple_ques">
        <item>What is your name?</item>
        <item>Where do you live?</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>

**values/simple_answers.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="simple_ans">
        <item>My name is Rabindra.</item>/
        <item>I live in Tandi.</item>/

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="np.com.rabindraacharya.androidinterview" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FrontPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Simple_question"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Tough_question"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Simple_question.java**

```
package np.com.rabindraacharya.androidinterview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Rabindra on 10/27/2015.
 */
public class Simple_question extends AppCompatActivity {
     TextView tvquestion,tvanswer, tvtotallength_yy,tvpresentindex_xx;
     ImageButton bleft, bshow, bright;
    String[] simple_question, simple_answer;
    int index;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questions);
        //setting value  to our variable and Textview

        simple_question = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.simple_ques);
        simple_answer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.simple_ans);

        onClickListener();


    }
    public void onClickListener(){
        index = 0;
        tvquestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvquestion);
        tvanswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvanswer);
        tvpresentindex_xx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvxx);
        tvtotallength_yy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvyy);

        tvquestion.setText(simple_question[index]);
        tvanswer.setText("Press \"A\" Button for the Answer");

***//problem on this line***
when this line is comment then the app will run other wise the app will get crash
    tvtotallength_yy.setText(simple_question.length);

               //index+1 is in INteger,so to change to string
        tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(index+1));




        bleft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bleft);
        bshow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bshowanswer);
        bright = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bright);

        bleft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        bshow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        bright.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: man bellow two responses are acceptable you have to Cast array length int to String and setContentView(R.layout.FrontPAge); insted of setContentView(R.layout.questions) other wise you will get nullpinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Crash because of trying to set int value in TextView.

```
`TextView.setText(int);` // wrong
```

Correct way to do it:

> `1) TextView.setText(Interger.toString(int));`
>
> `2) TextView.setText(String.valueOf(int));`
>
> `3) TextView.setText(""+int);`

Above are three ways where you can set integer value in TextView.

It seems that your string array might bu null.

Try to declare arrays.xml in values folder.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
        <resources>  

        <string-array name="simple_ans">
           <item>My name is Rabindra.</item>/
           <item>I live in Tandi.</item>/

        </string-array>

       <string-array name="simple_ques">
          <item>What is your name?</item>
          <item>Where do you live?</item>

       </string-array>

        </resources>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried with this code tvtotallength_yy.setText(String.valueOf(simple_question.length));
Again same problem

Comment: Where ? Which type of exception you are getting?

Comment: When i comment that line it work perfectly, if i remove comment tag then the app will crash.
Simple_question.java 
Line 41
 tvtotallength_yy.setText(String.valueOf(simple_question.length));

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Please scroll up, there u will see the Tag LogCat

Comment: My friend i am getting your point that you are getting crash on that line but i want to know the which type of exception it generated. Please Post your logcat.

Comment: Just above the FrontPage.xml you will see the keyword LogCat. Please click that LogCat you will see the pic.

Comment: Log your simple_question. Is it null?

Comment: I am totally beginner on Android. Just two day to started the android tut. so i don't have knowledge how to Log simple_question.

Comment: By viewing the tutorial i get little knowledge how to used log only

Comment: Ok Write : Log.e("simple_question ",""+simple_question );

Comment: 10-28 12:38:59.056  28080-28080/np.com.rabindraacharya.androidinterview E/simple_question﹕ [Ljava.lang.String;@4237efc8

10-28 12:39:10.736  28787-28787/np.com.rabindraacharya.androidinterview E/simple_question﹕ [Ljava.lang.String;@4237f7a0

10-28 12:39:59.176  28941-28941/np.com.rabindraacharya.androidinterview E/simple_question﹕ [Ljava.lang.String;@423845e8

Comment: @Ncit Cosmos : See my Edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
i have make another mistake so the app get crash.
There are 7 different layout of questions.xml. By mistake i kept different id on different layout. So it crash the app. Thanks for answer. It will help me on further day.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `questions.xml` as the layout file for `Simple_question.java` in which you dont have a TextView with id `tvxx` and `tvyy` which causes an `NPE` .See the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.questions);
```

Thus to solve it, you have to replace that with

```
setContentView(R.layout.FrontPAge);
```

Comment: Scroll Down the FrontPage there u will see questions.xml which has TextView having ID tvxx and tvyy

Comment: try to Toast the value of `simple_question.length` before setting it in the textview and check whether the Toast shows..

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),simple_question.length,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

Is this correct to toast simple.question.lenghth. And where to write this code? I paste it in the button of questions.xml, while click that button the app get crash

Comment: no no..you have to put this code just above `tvtotallength_yy.setText(simple_question.length);`

Comment: I am completely new on android programming. Just 2 day to start to learn the android by watching the tutorial.
The link below is the LogCat snap , 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/TJarQ.png

Comment: Thanks. 
There are 7 different layout for questions.xml. By Mistake i kept different id on other layout so this cause an crash. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

simple_question.length will return integer value . Try this

```
tvtotallength_yy.setText(String.valueOf(simple_question.length));
```

Comment: @NcitCosmos post your LogCat please.

Comment: try to hardcode your simple_question like this . remove `String[] simple_question` and add `String[] simple_question = {"question a","question b"};` after `setContentView`